# Android Gallery View Semi Circle Theme

Tags: android, styles, themes, gallery

Hi friends i am planned to work on user interface part, i wanted to make my own user interface for my gallery application. for example gallery view should be in semi circular view. can any one suggest me on this

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want something like this!!

[image]

you can find it in this [link](http://davy-leggieri.developpez.com/tutoriels/android/creation-carrousel/)
sorry but the link is in french language but you can find sources in the bottom of the page Mirror links

Comment: Thank you i can find some solution from this.

Answer (score 0):

You should start by learning more about the `Gallery` in general. This [link](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html) would make a good start.

Understand that code, go through the tutorials and begin experimenting on making incremental changes and seeing if they work.

Using this knowledge and prototype code start thinking about how you might go about creating your custom semi-circle gallery. Experiment and try some different things.

When/if you run into any issues or specific problems, post your question on a new thread and I'm sure you will find people willing to help you out.